# Почему конструктор работает с типом функции

Tags: c++

Есть такая структура:

```
template<class Func >
class Call
{
    Func* funcPtr;

public:
    Call(Func* func) :funcPtr{ func }
    {
        std::cout << typeid(Func).name() << std::endl;
    };
```

Если создаю объект так, то все ок:

```
Call<decltype(Beep)> a(Beep);
```

Если меняю тип в конструкторе на `Func` вместо `Func*` тоже все норм.

И тут уже вопрос, почему второй вариант работает, ведь `Func` будет типом функции а не указателем на функцию. Как мы можем создавать переменную типа функции?...

Comment: Тип в конструкторе после замены `Func *` на `Func` не меняется и по-прежнему остается указателем на функцию.

Comment: @user7860670 если убрать инициализацию поля и вывести тип, он меняется

Comment: Он не может меняться, функция не может передаваться по значению.

Comment: Переменная типа функции и есть указатель на функцию. Такое специальное правило в C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В параметрах функций автоматически происходит замена: если тип параметра - функция, то он заменяется на указатель на эту функцию. Более известно похожее правило, по которому в параметрах функций массивы заменяются на указатели.

То же самое происходит в типах (не-ти́повых) шаблонных параметров.

[`[dcl.fct]/5`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.fct-5)

> any parameter of type “array of `T`” or of function type `T` is adjusted to be “pointer to `T`”.